# Build Qt application on MacOS with debug symbols

Tags: macos, qt, qmake, debug-symbols, debug-information

How could I build an application for macOS written using Qt framework in Release mode with debug symbols information ?

I have tried what is suggested in Qt Doc:

```
# debug symbols
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE += $$QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE_WITH_DEBUGINFO
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += $$QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE_WITH_DEBUGINFO
QMAKE_OBJECTIVE_CFLAGS_RELEASE += $$QMAKE_OBJECTIVE_CFLAGS_RELEASE_WITH_DEBUGINFO
QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE += $$QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE_WITH_DEBUGINFO
```

But I get same output when I run nm command.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use built-in CONFIG flags to create separate debugging symbols:

`CONFIG+=force_debug_info CONFIG+=separate_debug_info`

(possibly add `CONFIG+=release CONFIG-=debug CONFIG-=debug_and_release` to make extra-sure to get a pure release + debug info build).

Note that this is what the “Profile” build in Qt Creator does by default.